# Comparing fingerprint live capture and template from DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, fingerprint

I'm stuck here when I try to compare the data from database to the live capture from the reader. The fingerprint is saved as image in the database.

I think I made a mistake here.

```
int conversionFormat = Convert.ToInt32(Constants.Formats.Fmd.ANSI);
Fmd fThumb = new Fmd((byte[])dr["FPThumb"], conversionFormat, Constants.WRAPPER_VERSION);

CompareResult compareResult = Comparison.Compare(anyFinger, 0, fThumb, 0);
```

When I try to compare the obj it gives me an error.

```
if (compareResult.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
{
   _sender.Reset = true;
   throw new Exception(compareResult.ResultCode.ToString());}
```

I think my mistake here is that when I convert the data from the database and I have no idea how.

Comment: As far as I understand, fingerprint scanner never stores the full image of the fingerprint. It will store the unique numeric code; using provided algorithm, in the database. So, if you are comparing against an image without the logic to convert that in same unique numeric code, it will fail.

Comment: do you have an idea how? ive been thinking to convert it into something since the capture image  DataResult<Fmd> resultConversion = FeatureExtraction.CreateFmdFromFid(captureResult.Data, Constants.Formats.Fmd.ANSI);
anyFinger = resultConversion.Data;

Comment: @Anand the sample provide doesn't have a database connection.